# Another way to instantiate the base part of a derived class with injecting the base in the ctor?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, constructor

I have a base and derived classes that combined have many parameters that need to be initialized. I want to use dependency injection for that, more specifically, to inject the base part when constructing a derivative.

For example

```
abstract class Baseclass
{
    private int a, b, c, d, e;

    public Baseclass(int A, int B, int C, int D, int E)
    {
        a = A;
        b = B;
        c = C;
        d = D;
        e = E;
    }

    public Baseclass(Baseclass basepart)
    {
        this = basepart; // error `this` is readonly

        a = basepart.a;  // so I use this method instead
        b = basepart.b;
        c = basepart.c;
        d = basepart.d;
        e = basepart.e;
    }
}

class Derived : Baseclass
{
    public Derived(Baseclass i_Basepart) : base(i_Basepart){}
}
```

The regular ctor and the "copy ctor" look very much the same, and since they have many parameters (more than this example) then it doesn't seem right. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Sounds like another point to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance

Comment: I agree with @alex.b. And further more, it's very likely you are violating the [SOLID principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) here.

Comment: @Steven why does it violate SOLID?

Comment: Base classes with dependencies tend to be used to apply cross-cutting concerns (CCC). When this happens SRP is violated, because the base class has many responsibilities (one for each CCC). OCP is violated because you will have to change the base class (and the ctor of all implementations) every time a new CCC is added. The base class will often expose many methods to the inheritors, while each inheritor will just use a few; this is a ISP violation.

Comment: But if the dependency is related to all of the derived classes of base, isn't it preferable to have the dependency in the base instead of in each of the derived? @Steven

Comment: It's possible to have one or perhaps two dependencies that all derived types use, but certainly not 5. That is definitely a code smell. Try hiding dependencies behind an [aggregate service](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) instead. And cross-cutting concerns are best applied using decorators instead of base classes. Again: Composition over inheritance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is where composition over inheritance comes into play. You can move your settings off into another class and pass that in:

```
class Baseclass
{
    private Parameters parameters;

    public BaseClass(Parameters parameters)
    {
        this.parameters = parameters;
    }
}

class Derived : Baseclass
{
    public Derived(Parameters parameters) : base(parameters) { }
}

class Parameters
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, etc.
}
```

You can even write some getters/setters in Baseclass that access the Parameters values in a transparent (to the caller) way. e.g.:

```
public A { get { return parameters.a; } set { parameters.a = value; } }
```